# angular get method API unable catch it

Tags: angular, typescript

GET http://localhost:4200/api/books (Not found) in console

**html**

```
    <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let book of softBook">
              Is: {{book.id}}, Name: {{book.name}}, category {{book.category}}
          </li>
        </ul>
```

**component.ts**

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { Book } from './Book';
        import { BookService } from './book.service';
        
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
        })
        export class AppComponent {
          title = 'demo';
        
        
          softBook : Book[];
        
          constructor(private bookService : BookService){}
          
          ngOnInit(): void {
            this.getSoftBooks();
          }
        
          getSoftBooks(){
            this.bookService.getBooksFromStore().subscribe(books=> this.softBook= books);
          }
        }
```

**module**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    
    import {BookService} from './book.service'

        import {InMemoryWebApiModule} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api'
        
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent
          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            AppRoutingModule,
             HttpClientModule,
            InMemoryWebApiModule
          ],
          providers: [BookService],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })
        export class AppModule { }
        
        
        export interface Book{
            id: number;
            name: string;
            category : string;
        }
```

**Service**

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import{HttpClient} from'@angular/common/http';
        import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
        import {Book} from './Book';
        
        
        @Injectable({
          providedIn: 'root'
        })
        export class BookService {
        
          bookUrl="/api/books";
        
          constructor(private http : HttpClient){}
        
          getBooksFromStore():Observable<Book[]>{
            return this.http.get<Book[]>(this.bookUrl);
          }
        }
        
        import{InMemoryDbService} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
```

**InMemoryDbService**

```
     export class TestData implements InMemoryDbService{
        
            createDb(){
                let bookDetails=[
                    {id:100, name: 'anguular by saho' , category: 'angualr'},
                    {id:101, name: 'core .net by saho' , category: 'angualr'},
                    {id:102, name: 'ngrx by saho' , category: 'angualr'},
                ];
        
                return {books: bookDetails};
            }
```

1)angular get method API unable catch it
2)angular get method API unable catch it
3)angular get method API unable catch it
4) angular get method API unable catch it
5)angular get method API unable catch it
6)angular get method API unable catch it

Comment: take a look through the documentation, your code is missing `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot` https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#simulate-a-data-server

Answer (score 0):

You need to add HttpClientModule to your AppModules imports array.

```
imports: [
    HttpClientModule
]
```

Comment: They changed the question after i answered - looks like your BE does not expose an API at that url now to answer the modified question.

Comment: annoying when that happens!